# How to know if Select query is empty

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query that i use to get the next id after my present id but when there is no more id after my present id i dont seem to know how to tell my code that this query returns no id.

```
public function select_pers_id($current_id){
    $que= $this->query("SELECT * FROM personality_question WHERE personality_question_id > $current_id ORDER BY $current_id ASC LIMIT 1");
    $rowp = $que->fetch_assoc();
    return $rowp['personality_question_id'];
}
```

and this is how i call it

```
$nid = $this->select_pers_id($currentid);
```

Have tried to use this blocks of code at different times to tell my system that the query returns no id but non of them have worked

```
if($nid=='null'){
    $sign = 'false';
    echo json_encode(array("value" => $sign, "value2" => $error));
}

if($nid==''){
    $sign = 'false';
    echo json_encode(array("value" => $sign, "value2" => $error));
}
 if(empty($nid)){
    $sign = 'false';
    echo json_encode(array("value" => $sign, "value2" => $error));
}
```

Been stuck here for hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll change your `select_pers_id()` to this :

```
public function select_pers_id($current_id){
    $que= $this->query("SELECT * FROM personality_question WHERE personality_question_id > $current_id ORDER BY $current_id ASC LIMIT 1");
    if ($que->num_rows > 0) {
      $rowp = $que->fetch_assoc();
      return $rowp['personality_question_id'];
    } else {
       return -1;
    }

}
```

You first check if the `SELECT` query returns a result by counting the returned rows using <s>`rowCount()`</s> **[EDIT :** with @CD001 enlightenment, you need to use `num_rows`**]**, if so, you return the wanted data, else you return an invalid `id` (-1 in this example)

Comment: The code looks more like `mysqli_` than `PDO` (so `rowCount()` is unlikely to work) - and besides, `rowCount()` [shouldn't be used with SELECT queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your validations are looking for either NULL or if it's empty.

To throw and error when $nid isn't existing I'd try:

```
if(!$nid) {
    $sign = 'false';
    echo json_encode(array("value" => $sign, "value2" => $error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check number of recors with `num_rows` then return result accoring to it

```
public function select_pers_id($current_id){
    $que= $this->query("SELECT * FROM personality_question WHERE personality_question_id > $current_id ORDER BY $current_id ASC LIMIT 1");
    if ($que->num_rows > 0) {
        return null;
    }
    $rowp = $que->fetch_assoc();
    return $rowp['personality_question_id'];
}
```

Then to check

```
$nid = $this->select_pers_id($currentid);
if($nid==null){
    $sign = 'false';
    echo json_encode(array("value" => $sign, "value2" => $error));
}
```